# Upload multiple images to php script from android

Tags: php, image, file, upload, http-post

I am posting multiple images from android to a PHP script using the latest apache HTTPmultipart.

I have created a loop in android to load the multipart like this:

```
try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlServer);
            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();

            //Loop to add images    
            for (int i = 0; i<selectedList.size(); i++) {
                File passFile = selectedList.get(i);
                ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(passFile, "image/png");
                String partName = "image" + i;
                mpEntity.addPart(partName, cbFile);

            }
```

This works fine and loads the image to my PHP for the first image using the following code:

```
uploadDir = './';      //Uploading to directory specified

$file = basename($_FILES['image0']['name']);

$uploadFile = $file;
$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999999999); 
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;


if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image0']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
} else {
    echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}

if ($_FILES['image']['size']> 100000000) {
    exit("Your file is too large."); 
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image0']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'result'=>$newName,
            'msg'=>'Report added successfully.'
            )
        );
```

I am having problem however getting more images into PHP. I have tried the following:

```
$currentName = 'image' + 0;
$file = basename($_FILES[$currentName]['name']);
```

but this does not work. will be creating a loop so 0 above will be replaced by i but this is not recognized when creating a file.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate use dot rather than plus sign.

```
$currentName = 'image'.$i;
```

'image'+0 is just 0. Then replace 'image0' with $currentName. Don`t forget to fix the following line, you should use 'image0', not 'image'

```
if ($_FILES['image']['size'])...
```

Comment: rookie mistaken ive been coding in java for days! ill try later thanks